# C# Replace "Whole words only" using RegEx and dictionary

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary, replace

I would like to create code, to replace words contained in one file, using another text file as a dictionary (struct.: Key sep.:tab Value).

Current code:

```
var fileDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
   File.ReadLines(dictionaryPath, Encoding.Default)
  .Select(line => line.Split('  '))
  .ToDictionary(data => data[0], data => data[1]), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);//create dictionary based on text file

for (int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++)
{
   var output = fileString[i].ToString();// current row, taked from other file
   var replaced = Regex.Replace(output, String.Join("|", fileDictionary.Keys.Select(Regex.Escape)), m => fileDictionary[m.Value], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   var result = replaced.ToString();
   outputFile += result.ToString();
   outputFile += "\r\n";
}
```

Until now, everything worked fine, I'm using RegEx to replace words collected in the dictionary, but I have a problem with replacing type "whole words only".

I decided to use pattern like @"\bsomeword\b" but when I implemented it as described below:

```
 var replaced = Regex.Replace(output, String.Join("|", 
         String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", 
         fileDictionary.Keys.Select(Regex.Escape))), 
         m => fileDictionary[m.Value], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The code doesn't return any results. Final text file looks like the original file. Nothing happens. I realize, the problem is in dictionary key, when I am using the pattern I actually change key and the new one does not exist in the current dictionary. So if the key does not exist, the value is not replaced.

Does anybody any suggestions how to fix that? Or maybe somebody knows some other way to replace whole words only, using RegEx and dictionary?

Comment: Try `\w*` as your pattern instead. Your pattern of `\b{0}\b` doesn't really make much sense, as it is looking for a word-boundary character exactly zero times, followed by another word-boundary character

Comment: Try "[^ ]\w+[ $.!?]"  Code will accept at beginning a space or the start of the string and also accept at the end a space, end of string, question mark, exclamation mark or period.

Comment: Just to point out the differences between my pattern and jdwng's, mine will match "sales" from "[sales]", while his will not.  Which pattern to chose is based on your actual requirements.

Comment: @jdweng your pattern captures the ending non-word character, which will probably cause a problem.

Comment: What problem will it cause?  You can always remove the end character with a Trim() method after the match.

Comment: He is doing a replace on the match.  If he wants to replace "cat" in "cat and dog" with "mouse", using your regex he will end up with "mouseand dog" without manually adding the space.  The problem becomes more apparent if the ending character is one of your punctuation symbols, as he won't know which character to add.  The pattern that doesn't capture the ending symbol would be `[^ ]\w+(?=[ $.!?])`, it just puts the ending character inside a zero-width look ahead.  You may also want to add a comma to your pattern, or it won't match words in things like "one, two, three".

Comment: Do you need to treat things like "dog's" in the "the dog's water bowl" as a single word? if so, my pattern needs to change to `[\w']*`.  There may be other characters you need to consider adding to that set. `-` would probably be a god addition as well.

Comment: Have you tried assigning String.Join("|", 
         String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", 
         fileDictionary.Keys.Select(Regex.Escape))) to a variable and adding a breakpoint to see the value, checking it's how you expect it?

Comment: Thank everybody for help, I found solution in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the pattern wasn't parsing correctly from the dictionary

```
 var replaced = Regex.Replace(fileString, String.Join("|", fileDictionary.Select(m => @"\b" + Regex.Escape(m.Key) + @"\b")), m => fileDictionary[m.Value], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Utilising a StringBuilder for your output would be more efficient also.

Comment: Have you any suggestion how could I substitute it? I am asking, because now I have a lot of problems with the time of the process. I talkin about huge file (dictionary around 3k rows and basic file 26k).

Comment: Are you using StringBuilder or just prepending the string?

Comment: My outputFile is declared as simple string and there is no StringBuilder in the code, I just prepending the string.

Comment: Although by the sounds of the files size I would expect it to take some time prepending a string excessive number of times is very inefficient. Every time you prepend the string it creates a new string as it’s immutable. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder

Try utilising StringBuilder within your code and see if you notice any difference. Either way though I would defiantly use StringBuilder in this case.